# Spring Boot MVC - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am developing a basic web application using Spring Boot using Maven. When I run the app, I get the following error, and my app stops running:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).Request method 'POST' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

What I want to do is, I want to get user input from textbox that is inside a form inside an html page (`index.html`), then later I will be processing that data. In JSF, we can do this simply by using getters and setters that are kept inside simple POJO class. But in Spring MVC, it seems bit more complicated because of handling HTTP requests manually.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Here is my `IndexController.java` class

```
package com.ilter.application;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.ilter.model.Index;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/static/index")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("index", new Index());
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/static/index")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Index index, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("index", index);
        return "/tags.html"; //after data is gathered, user is redirected to tags.html page
    }

}
```

Here is `Application.java` class

```
package com.ilter.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ilter.model"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my simple pojo that is kept inside `com.ilter.model` package

```
package com.ilter.model;

public class Index {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Here is my index.html webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>My Tool</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
        src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div role="navigation">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Report</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Past
                            Reports History</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="navbar-text"> About us </span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <form class="form" action="#" th:action="@{/index}"
        th:object="${index}" method="post">
        <h3 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 50px;">Enter Person's
            Name</h3>
        <div class="md-form active-cyan-2 mb-3" id="search"
            style="padding-left: 150px">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"
                aria-label="Search" th:field="*{name}">
        </div>
        <div id="div-btn">
            <button id="prm-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go
                (To the next page)</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And at last, here is my POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ilter</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.3]</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried almost all possible solutions on the internet, checked almost all of the questions asked that is similar to mine, but none was helpful and still couldn't solved it. I used to use JSF framework for web application development and since it is considered jurrasic now I thought it was time to move on to a newer framework such as Spring. But CRUD operations and HTTP requests gave me some hard time to be honest.

I don't know the root issue, it might be improper usage of CRUD operations, missing Maven packages or even folder stucture.Anyways, I have spent some time on this issue and all the help and ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Some toolstip. In Spring MVC, you put the html files in template folder, not static folder. And the name on @PostMapping("name") is the alias for the method, so in your submit form, try to change the th:action="@{/index}" to th:action="@{/static/index}". It should work. /tags.html isnt required too. just "tags", should work fine.

Comment: Your thymleaf action in index.html is different from your mapping. Also why are you using static folder? Static folder is used for static resources like css, javascripts or imgs. Your templates should reside in templates folder.

Comment: thanks for the tips @AlexandreGuerreiro and yogsma. I used the static folder I guess because I saw it in following example [http://zetcode.com/springboot/static/]. But sure as a next step, I'll put them in template folder and inform you all about the result.

Comment: I have moved the index.html to templates folder, but now I get the following error : `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'index' available as request attribute`. As I made some research, I found out that I need to add `modelAttribute="loginModel" ` component to my html page, which seems not possible since this component works with jsp. I guess I will need to find out how to add this component to an html page, otherwise I'll have to set my pages as .jsp instead of .html.

Comment: I have solved it by adding `ViewController` and implementing `WebMvcConfigurer `. Also, I have made some changes inside my Indexcontroller class such as removing `Model` and adding `BindingResult` parameters. Now I can get user input successfully.